# How to implement an independent custom UIView with nib file in Swift?

Tags: uiview, swift3, xib

Many times I would like to implement custom UIViews, but I always have the same problem : my IBOutlets are nil when I want to use them.

I tried everything I could see on the web, but nothing works...

```
class ImagePickerView: UIView, ImagePickerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageViewSelected: UIImageView!


//MARK: - Initializers

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.onAddPicturePressed))
    tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //imageViewSelected = UIImageView()
}


//MARK: - ImagePickerDelegate

func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {}

func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {

    self.imageViewSelected.image = images[0] // (the limit is set to 1 image)
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


//MARK: - Events

func onAddPicturePressed(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        self.backgroundColor = CustomsColors.gray
    } else if gesture.state == .ended {
        self.backgroundColor = CustomsColors.lightGray
    }

    showImagePicker()
}


//MARK: - Utils

func showImagePicker() {
    let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.imageLimit = 1
    Configuration.mainColor = CustomsColors.green
    Configuration.cancelButtonTitle = "Annuler"
    Configuration.doneButtonTitle = "OK"
    Configuration.noImagesTitle = "Pas d'images disponibles"

    self.parentViewController?.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

I tried `self = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ImagePickerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ImagePickerView` but I can't asign self.

I want something really simple, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Make an object of  ImagePickerView in UIViewController class, where you want to add this view. Then add this as subview and set frames.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps in which view controller you want to add nib:

1. **Make Object:**

   var priceView : FV_ViewToShowPrice!
2. **Give Frame:**

   priceView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FV_ViewToShowPrice", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! FV_ViewToShowPrice

   priceView.frame = self.view.bounds
3. **Add in view:**

   self.view.addSubview(priceView)

Comment: It's not possible to avoid to instanciate the ImagePickerView in code and do it automatically via the Storyboard ? (setting the class of my UIView on "ImagePickerView") ?